# Reducing a state space equation to a controllable and observable equation

Tags: state-space

I need to check that I'm solving this question correctly and where to go afterwards. I'm reducing the given equation to a controllable and observable equation.

[image: State Space Equation]

From the picture, it is clear the A matrix is in Jordan form where λ1 is in a 3x3 Jordan block and λ2 is in a 2x2 Jordan block. The B matrix that corresponds to λ1 is the top 3 elements. Since the third element is 0, λ1 is not controllable.
The B matrix that corresponds to λ2 is the bottom 2 elements. Since the 5th element is 1, it is controllable.

For Observability, I need to check the C matrix. Since the first element is 0, λ1 is not observable, and since the fourth element is 0, λ2 is not observable.

So I know λ1 is not controllable or observable and λ2 is controllable but not observable. How do I write the corresponding state equation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got the solution to this problem. As the original matrix is in Jordan form, it can be broken down and reduced to the following. Note the change in the variable subscripts.

[image: Rewritten uncontrollable and unobservable]

Rewritten uncontrollable and unobservable

[image: Reduced Controllable and unobservable]

Reduced Controllable and unobservable

[image: Rewritten Controllable and unobservable]

Rewritten Controllable and unobservable

[image: Reduced Controllable and Observable]

Reduced Controllable and Observable

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem wants you to do the [Kalman decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kalman_decomposition) and since they are in a Jordan normal form it should be quick to do. From the wording of the problem itself it is not really clear, but you should probably only represent the part of the system that is both controllable and observable (and discard the rest of it?).

Comment: By the way, this is the same as doing the 'minreal' of the system in Matlab/Octave

Comment: So if the whole system is not observable then ...?

Comment: If the whole system is not observable you have \$C = 0\$, other than that, at least one mode/state will be observable. in your case, I think that two states will be both observable and controllable.